# How to get the current page's full url in React Native Web Expo?

Tags: react-native, routes, expo, react-native-web

A url to my website could be e.g. custom.mywebsite.com or custom2.mywebsite.com.
How can I get the full url of this current page that contains 'custom.mywebsite.com' in my React Native for Web app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Expo Linking](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/linking/?redirected#handling-links-into-your-app) you can get the full URL on app launch by calling

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    console.log(url);
});
```